# How to refresh parent window update panel from child window closing

Tags: javascript, asp.net

I am trying this code:

```
function CloseMe() {
    window.opener.location.href = window.opener.location.href;
    if (window.opener.progressWindow)
        window.opener.progressWindow.close();
    window.close();
}
```

But it doesn't work properly.

How to do I refresh the parent window after the child window closes?

Comment: when we  click on  child close button then parent page  load but i want to that only repeater bind in parent window

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Try this code:**

```
function CloseMe() {
    window.Parent.location.href = window.Parent.location.href;
    if (window.Parent.progressWindow) window.Parent.progressWindow.close();
        window.close();
}
```